# Compositing a transformation in glm and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math

From Linear Algebra, if you have a translation matrix:

[image]

and a scaling matrix:

[image]
The net effect that we translate and scale is given by:

[image]

Now I just use VSCode to see how the translation is handled by `glm` for using these operations:

```
//my code
glm::mat4 modelMatrix(1.0f); 
modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5f, 0.5f));
modelMatrix = glm::scale(modelMatrix,glm::vec3(1.5, 1.5, 1.0));
```

the code for glm::translate is :

```
//glm code
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, Q> translate(mat<4, 4, T, Q> const& m, vec<3, T, Q> const& v)
    {
        mat<4, 4, T, Q> Result(m);
        Result[3] = m[0] * v[0] + m[1] * v[1] + m[2] * v[2] + m[3];
        return Result;
    }
```

which is essentially altering the third column of the identity matrix and turning `modelMatrix` to the translation matrix T, **but what is surprising is, it doesn't form the composite transformation
matrix**, instead it does this:

```
//glm code
  template<typename T, qualifier Q>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, Q> scale(mat<4, 4, T, Q> const& m, vec<3, T, Q> const& v)
    {
        mat<4, 4, T, Q> Result;
        Result[0] = m[0] * v[0];
        Result[1] = m[1] * v[1];
        Result[2] = m[2] * v[2];
        Result[3] = m[3];
        return Result;
    }
```

which is essentially just scaling the columns of the transformation matrix like so:
(I've put the value of the translation matrix as shown in *my code above*):

[image]

Which is not the composite transformation matrix I expected it to be at all, which was  from what I learned from the Linear Algebra theory:

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: Is the second matrix from bottom really the result you are getting? Shouldn't there be a 1.0 in the third row/third column since you are using (1.5, 1.5, 1) as scaling factors in your code? For everything else: Your multiplication order is wrong. Your code calculates T * S, not S * T.

Comment: @BDL, it seems I did a typo.

Comment: It's the difference between scaling then translating, or translating then scaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix multiplication order is wrong. The example code calculates T * S instead of S * T. [Matrix multiplications are not commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Non-commutativity), thus the result defers from your expectation.

The following code should produce the result you need:

```
glm::mat4 modelMatrix(1.0f); 
modelMatrix = glm::scale(modelMatrix,glm::vec3(1.5, 1.5, 1.0));
modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5f, 0.5f));
```

Comment: this is true, but, it seems that it's the way GLM handles things because one would expect that consecutive matrix calls would tack matrices to the left instead of right.